# Saving 3 php variables from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

```
<?php 


include ('config.php');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Platser</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="glassbox">

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['Spara'])){

    }

    $antal = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Grupp ID` FROM `Elevgrupper` WHERE `Grupp ID`=25");
    $num = $antal->num_rows;

    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Namn`, `Efternamn` FROM `Elever` WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `Användar ID` FROM `Elevgrupper` WHERE `Grupp ID` = 25)");

    for ($i = 1; $i<=$num; $i++){
        $get_coords = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM coords WHERE id = '" . $i . "'");
        $row = $get_coords->fetch_assoc();
        $ok = $res->data_seek($i-1);
        $row1 = $res->fetch_assoc();

        //
        $x = $row['x_pos'];
        $y = $row['y_pos']; 
        echo '<div id="e'. $i .'" class="e" style="left:'.$x.'px; top:'.$y.'px;"><p id="p' . $i .'">'. $row1["Namn"] . " " . $row1["Efternamn"] . '</p></div>';
        }

?>
</div>
<form action="<?echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input onclick="spara();" type="submit" name="Spara">
</form>

<div id="respond"></div>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var antal = document.getElementsByClassName("e");
        for (var i = 1; i <= antal.length; i++) {
                $("#e" + i).draggable({ 
                containment: '#glassbox', 
                scroll: false
                });
            }
        });

    function spara(){
        var antal = document.getElementsByClassName("e");
        for (var i = 1; i <= antal.length; i++) {
            var coords=[];
            var coord = $("#p" + i).position();
            var item={ coordTop:  coord.left, coordLeft: coord.top  };
            coords.push(item);
            var order = { coords: coords };
            $.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response){    
        });
    }
}


</script>

</html>



<?php
if(!$_POST["data"]){
    echo "Nothing Sent";
    exit;
}

include ('config.php');

$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);

foreach($data->coords as $item) {
    //Extract X number for panel
    $coord_X = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordTop);
    //Extract Y number for panel
    $coord_Y = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordLeft);
    //escape just-in case
    $x_coord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $coord_X);
    $y_coord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $coord_Y);

    //Setup Query
    $sql = "UPDATE coords SET x_pos = '" . $x_coord . "' WHERE id"= . substr($data->id, -1) .;
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    $sql = "UPDATE coords SET y_pos = "'. $y_coord .'"  WHERE id"= . substr($data->id, -1) .;
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

}

//Return Success
echo "success";



?>
```

If I am not mistaken everything except the spara function should work and it's driving me crazy since I don't get even get any error messages, seems like it runs through the entire script without errors and without saving anything.

What I am trying to do is a teacher tool that from a database which contains all students places out benches that you can drag around and move to your choosing so that you can decide seats for everyone without having to do much work as the teacher. And I want the layout to save by pressing a button which runs the function.

Comment: please provide 1) a console.log of your order 2) a screenshot of the request that is being sent (Dev tools -> network -> select the outgoing request (xhr) -> Query String Parameters (in Chrome) )

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line could be wrong:

```
$.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response)
```

Usually I would have something like this:

```
$.post('updatecoords.php', {data: somevar}, function(response)
```

Give that a try, assign `$.toJSON(order)` to a variable and pass it as suggested.

UPDATE:
Based on Domeniks feedback below, you probably just need to do this:

```
$.post('/updatecoords.php', somevar, function(response)
```

Comment: you need to send `{$.toJSON(order)}` without the data:, because you already use key:value pairs

Comment: okay, now then. are you sure you didn't mean `/updaterecords.php`? It's on the same domain right? But you should put an absolute path

Comment: @delboy1978uk yeah I'm sure they're on the same domain, the code has worked before, but now that I need more than one box and save on a button instead of when moving them it had to be done differently

Comment: @helmjävel please provide a `console.log` of `$.toJSON(order)`. That might solve the problem.

Comment: @helmjävel you are sending `var order = { coords: coords };` so you need to either change that to `var order = { data: coords };` or simply change the ajax to `data: coords` and remove the `var order`

Comment: @delboy1978uk I changed the code to 

         var senddata = $.toJSON(order);
         $.post('updatecoords.php', senddata, function(response){ 

but it's just the same, it works, but nothing happens

Comment: Please try Domeniks suggestion above your last comment.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner changing the var order to data: coords did not change anything either